# Create a role on a BlackBerry Enterprise Server using the BlackBerry Administrator API?

Tags: blackberry, wsdl

It's pretty easy to create an administrator user on the BlackBerry Administrator API, following the documentation.  All administrator users have to be assigned a role, and roles are easy to look up (Example using python and suds):

```
organisation_id = 0
locale = 'en_US'
display_name = 'Mac Chapman'
username = 'maccy'
password = 'password'
role_id = None
for role in ws.service.findRoles(organisation_id, locale).roles:
    if role.localeNameAndDescription[0].name == 'Security Administrator':
        role_id = role.roleId
print ws.service.createBASAuthenticatedAdministratorUser(organisation_id, display_name, role_id, username, password)
```

But I cannot for the life of me figure out how to create a new role within the API. Is it possible?